# upper bound for norm features inequality with arbitrary vector

Tags: matrices, inequality, transpose

Let $Q$ be a positive definite matrix and $w$ be an arbitrary vector.
How we can conclude about upper bound of $ww^{T}$ if $w^T Q^{-1} w \leq 1$?

Comment: I would like to inform you that while StackExchange is a Q/A site, [more than just a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/) is expected from the asker. Try to focus your question to an actual and specific problem you have faced. If you can, include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do. If you are stuck, provide definitions and your own background. Write down what you know and generally try to be constructive. If you can, provide motivation and context for the problem. This is meant to be an exchange, both ways, as the site name implies.

Comment: i mean what do we can say about wwT? , is it wwT≤||Q||I(identity matrix)??

Comment: Hint: Since $Q$ is symmetric, there exists an orthognal matrix $T$ such that $T^tQT$ is diagonal.